# configure in Dockerfile a mount point and extract files to that mount point

Tags: docker, mounted-volumes

I have a kubernetes cluster on google cloud platform.

I'm extending the official php docker image to support certbot and others.

this is what I have so far:

```
FROM php:7.1.13-apache-jessie

RUN bash -c 'echo deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main >> /etc/apt/sources.list'
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y python-certbot-apache -t jessie-backports
```

is there a way to configure what will happen when the pod is started ?

I want to check if the user mounted empty volumes for specific directories and if they are empty to fill them with the relevant content.

for example.. I want to store `/etc/apache2` default configuration somewhere... so if the user mounted an empty volume to `/etc/apache2`, to fill it with the relevant file.

same for `/var/www/html`.

any ideas how to do so ?

thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to configure what will happen when the pod is started ?

That is what your ENTRPYPOINT/CMD can be for: you can have your own image with an ENTRYPOINT script which will:

- do your checks
- call the [php-entrypoint as the official php image does](https://github.com/docker-library/php/blob/f4baf0edbc4e05e241938c68bcc7c9635707583d/7.2/stretch/cli/Dockerfile#L184-L186).

That being said, copying dynamically stuff from the host is not a practice I have seen often (you don't know what the local host has), even though [`docker cp`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cp/) might do that.
Maybe stopping with a warning message is better.